# HTTPS mysteriously lost after simple 301 redirection

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following .htaccess

```
# force https and wwww ( works as expected )
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301] 

# force cache busting via incrementable value (00x) 
RewriteRule ^launch-test/?$ /launch-test-004/ [NC,R=301,L]

# call the appropriate script
RewriteRule ^launch-test-004/?$ /wid-test/php/start.php [NC]
```

The problem I'm facing is that the 2nd rule (the one used for cache busting) reverts HTTPS back to HTTP, which makes urls unsecure.

Any reason for that?

Comment: I fail to understand what that second rule is meant to do...  If you want to prevent caching, then so that using the correct http headers. Such a static rule won't get you far, I'd say. If at all you would have to implement something dynamic.

Comment: Anyway that second rule does not by itself redirect you to another protocol scheme. There has to be some additional effect you did not mention here. I suggest you start debugging: open your browsers development console (typically F12) and monitor the actual requests done and the redirections you receive back. You also want to compare that wilh the access logfile entries your http server writes. You need to understand in details what is happening. That is something we cannot somehow _guess_ without having access to your setup.

Comment: @arkascha I've tried everything and this method is the only one that doesn't need even a soft refresh on Chrome. Tell me if I'm wrong but HTTP headers don't work for my scenario in which I need to have any client forget the old script after a script update has be done.

Comment: @arkascha The thing is that removing only that line won't cause the HTTPS to change back to HTTP. That's why I assumed it came for there.

Comment: I cannot say what you tried and what your setup is. But disabling client side response caching is a standard and it certainly does work. This sounds like a typical xy problem: http://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing this solved the problem:

```
# force https and wwww ( works as expected )
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301] 

# force cache busting via incrementable value (00x) 
RewriteRule ^launch-test/?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/launch-test-004/ [R=301]

# call the appropriate script
RewriteRule ^launch-test-004/?$ /wid-test/php/start.php [NC]
```

Unfortunately, it was unsuccessful at serving as a cache busting method but it's not the point of this question anyway.